# Are Office Addins supported on OSX?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office365-apps

I'm trying to develop addins for Outlook 2016 for Mac, doesn't seem like it's possible to add command buttons to the ribbon. I am able to create only custom panes in the Read/Update windows for Message and Appointment.

Anybody knows why ? The Windows version works as advertised.

Comment: [It would seem to depend on the type of add in](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macword/add-ins-for-word-for-mac-2016/938a4827-a0dd-417d-93d3-e3c52f291439?auth=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean [these kinds of add-in command buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt267546.aspx), Mac Outlook doesn't support them *yet*.

Comment: But it's expected that the support will be rolled out in the near future: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac/add-ins-in-outlook-2016-for-mac/204dc412-b69f-4cae-bf21-6904e5e03d20